# Proper lme4 equation with fixed and random effects for group differences

Tags: r, lme4

I have a dataset[Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKXYJ.png) comprised of whole fish concentrations (LAB_RESULT.x), filet fish concentrations (LAB_RESULT.y), and species name (COMMON_NAME.x). I am attempting to run a linear mixed effects model to determine the relationship between filet to whole fish concentrations by species, and if there is a difference among species in this model. This is a step to eventually see if a single linear model works for all species or if there is significant differences between species.

I put together the model:

```
lmer(LAB_RESULT.x ~ COMMON_NAME.x + (1|LAB_RESULT.y), 
     data = SHFvFilet)
```

and get an output[Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4m0Y.png), but am struggling to determine if this is the proper equation for this question, as well as how to properly determine what the output is representing.
From my understanding this is showing that for individual species whole fish concentration, species such as Largemouth Bass are significantly different than the overall model, and should not be included in an overall model, while those that are not significant could be included in an overall model. I am also using the lmerTest package with Satterthwaite's method being used to produce p values.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think this question belong on stat exchange it seems you are asking a statistics question and not a programming question